# Cropper.js crop programmatically

Tags: cropper, cropperjs

I am using cropper.js (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) to manipulate images, but I could not find a way to crop my image programmatically.

What I am trying to do is create a cropped preview immediately after initialising the cropper.

```
var cropper = new Cropper(document.getElementById('img'), {
    autoCrop: true,
    autoCropArea: 1,
    aspectRatio: 500 / 660,
    minCropBoxWidth: 500,
    minCropBoxHeight: 660,
    viewMode: 2
});
```

I have `autoCrop` enabled, but if I try to get the data with `cropper.getCroppedCanvas()` it returns `null`.

I noticed that `cropper.cropped` is false, so probably I need to trigger the initial cropping, but no idea how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I realised that I was trying to generate the preview image too early.
the problem was that the `cropper` was not fully initialised yet.

Calling the logic when `ready` is fired fixed it:

```
var cropper = new Cropper(document.getElementById('img'), {
    autoCrop: true,
    autoCropArea: 1,
    aspectRatio: 500 / 660,
    minCropBoxWidth: 500,
    minCropBoxHeight: 660,
    viewMode: 2,
    ready: function() {
        generatePreview();
    }
});
```